# Bounded type parameters

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

Sorry guys, this might be a naive question.

I am a little bit confused by bounded type parameter and wildcard. What's the difference between `<T extends String>` and `<? extends String>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up some things here.

`<T extends String>` is used when you declare a generic class.

`<? extends String>` is used on instances from classes that are already generic.

Let’s take the interface “List” from the collections framework for example:
`List <E>` is the same like `List <E  extends Object>` meaning that you can use the list with every datatype that inherits from Object.

The wildcard `<?>` can only be used on Classes that are already generic. Taking the example from above with `List<E>.`Let’s say you have a method that is using the List, but you don’t want to allow every datatype that inherits from Object.

You could use a distinct datatype like:

```
public void myMethod(List<String> list){
//…
}
```

But you could also use a range of datatypes that you want to allow:

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends String> list{
//..
}
```

In the second example you could use every datatype that is covariant with string i.e. is a child of string.

**Tldr:**

Bounds `<T extends String>` are used to declare the range of datatypes a  generic class is supporting.

Wildcards `<? extends String>` are used on classes that are already generic and restrict/limit the given datatypes to a certain range.

Answer (score 1):

The second one basically means: you really don't care about the actual type. You just care that it would extend String.

In other words: if your code does not need to use "T" anywhere; then you can make your intention more clear by "not at all mentioning that type name T".

For more technical background, one of the best resources is the work of [Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ203).